# Android: how to check if a View inside of ScrollView is visible?

Tags: android, scrollview, visible

I have a `ScrollView` which holds a series of `Views`.  I would like to be able to determine if a view is currently visible (if any part of it is currently displayed by the `ScrollView`). I would expect the below code to do this, surprisingly it does not:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
view.getDrawingRect(bounds);

Rect scrollBounds = new Rect(scroll.getScrollX(), scroll.getScrollY(), 
        scroll.getScrollX() + scroll.getWidth(), scroll.getScrollY() + scroll.getHeight());

if(Rect.intersects(scrollBounds, bounds))
{
    //is  visible
}
```

Comment: I'm curious how you got this to work. I'm trying to do the same thing but a ScrollView can only host 1 direct child. Are your "series of views" wrapped in another layout inside the ScrollView? That's how mine are laid out but when I do that none of the answers given here work for me.

Comment: Yes, my series of views are inside a LinearLayout, which is the 1 child of the ScrollView.  Qberticus' answer worked for me.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use `View#getHitRect` instead of `View#getDrawingRect` on the view you're testing. You can use `View#getDrawingRect` on the *`ScrollView`* instead of calculating explicitly.

Code from `View#getDrawingRect`:

```
 public void getDrawingRect(Rect outRect) {
        outRect.left = mScrollX;
        outRect.top = mScrollY;
        outRect.right = mScrollX + (mRight - mLeft);
        outRect.bottom = mScrollY + (mBottom - mTop);
 }
```

Code from `View#getHitRect`:

```
public void getHitRect(Rect outRect) {
        outRect.set(mLeft, mTop, mRight, mBottom);
}
```

Comment: Where should i call this methods?

Comment: @Qberticus How to call the methods ? I am using it and it is always returning false. Please let me know

Comment: Exactly where to call these methods?

Answer (score 212):

This works:

```
Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
if (imageView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
    // Any portion of the imageView, even a single pixel, is within the visible window
} else {
    // NONE of the imageView is within the visible window
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. To make it clearer: returns true if view is completely or partially visible; false means the view is completely not visible.

Comment: [+1] I used this code to get `GridView`/`ListView`/`GridViewWithHeader` working with `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Comment: Could someone please explain why this works? `getHitRect` returns a rect in the parent coordinates, but `getLocalVisibleRect` returns a rect in the scrollview's local coordinates, doesn't it?

Comment: This doesn't cover overlaps, if Child View is overlapped by another child element, it will still return true

Comment: I think the first two line could be deleted,Am i right? scrollBounds will be write in getLocalVisibleRect @Bill Mote

Comment: No.  First you need to create an instance of Rect().  Then you need to populate it with the coordinates from the ScrollView().  Once you know the coordinates of the ScrollView you validate them against the ImageView's visible rectangle. @chefish

Comment: Yes ,we need an instance of Rect.But is it necessary to getHitRect. Is there any different if I use a Rect (0,0-0,0).We can see getLocalVisibleRect call getGlobalVisibleRect.And Rect is set here r.set(0, 0, width, height);.@BillMote

Comment: `   public boolean getGlobalVisibleRect(Rect r, Point globalOffset) {
        int width = mRight - mLeft;
        int height = mBottom - mTop;
        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
            r.set(0, 0, width, height);
            if (globalOffset != null) {
                globalOffset.set(-mScrollX, -mScrollY);
            }
            return mParent == null || mParent.getChildVisibleRect(this, r, globalOffset);
        }
        return false;
    }`

Comment: I actually used nothing but simple ScrollView and TextView inside; to just test if it really works. To my surprise, it was always "invisible". Even though it was on the screen :))

Answer (score 66):

If you want to detect that the view is **FULLY** visible:

```
private boolean isViewVisible(View view) {
    Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    mScrollView.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds);

    float top = view.getY();
    float bottom = top + view.getHeight();

    if (scrollBounds.top < top && scrollBounds.bottom > bottom) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer =)
In my case I changed the if like this:

scrollBounds.top <= top && scrollBounds.bottom => bottom

Comment: +1 Helton if your view is either pushed against the top or bottom fo your scroll view you will need the <= or >= respectively

Comment: Have you really tested this? It always returns false in the most simple layout ScrollView and TextView as a child.

Comment: Whats diff between getHitRect() & getDrawingRect()? Please guide

Comment: This code only works if the view is added directly to the root of ScrollView container. Check Phan Van Linh's answer if you want to handle a child view in a child view etc.

Answer (score 28):

This extension help detect view **fully** visible.
It also work if your `View` is a child of child of ... of `ScrollView` (eg: `ScrollView` -> `LinearLayout` -> `ContraintLayout` -> ... -> `YourView`).

```
fun ScrollView.isViewVisible(view: View): Boolean {
    val scrollBounds = Rect()
    this.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds)
    var top = 0f
    var temp = view
    while (temp !is ScrollView){
        top += (temp).y
        temp = temp.parent as View
    }
    val bottom = top + view.height
    return scrollBounds.top < top && scrollBounds.bottom > bottom
}
```

**Note**

1) `view.getY()` and `view.getX()` return the x,y value to **FIRST PARENT**.

2) Here is example about how `getDrawingRect` will return
[image]
[Link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Y7r_ybXhUFhx1MufaGye16EckiyCDywuD097oLfzsV0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I wanted a solution where method should return false if view is hidden under keyboard and this does the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

My Solution is use `NestedScrollView` Scroll element:

```
    final Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    scroller.getHitRect(scrollBounds);

    scroller.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

            if (myBtn1 != null) {

                if (myBtn1.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
                    if (!myBtn1.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)
                            || scrollBounds.height() < myBtn1.getHeight()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "BTN APPEAR PARCIALY");
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "BTN APPEAR FULLY!!!");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "No");
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: requires API 23+

Comment: @SolidSnake , no you need to import different class, it works fine

Comment: Working example. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

To expand a bit on Bill Mote's answer using getLocalVisibleRect, you may want to check if the view is only partially visible:

```
Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
if (!imageView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)
    || scrollBounds.height() < imageView.getHeight()) {
    // imageView is not within or only partially within the visible window
} else {
    // imageView is completely visible
}
```

Comment: This does not work.. even partially visible view is categorized as completely visible

Answer (score 9):

```
public static int getVisiblePercent(View v) {
        if (v.isShown()) {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            v.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
            double sVisible = r.width() * r.height();
            double sTotal = v.getWidth() * v.getHeight();
            return (int) (100 * sVisible / sTotal);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is different from what ab11 asked for. isShown() only checks for the visibility flag, not whether the view is in the visible region of the screen.

Comment: @Romain Guy The code do not cover when a view is total scrolled away the screen.It should be`  public static int getVisiblePercent(View v) {
        if (v.isShown()) {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            boolean isVisible = v.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
            if (isVisible) {
                double sVisible = r.width() * r.height();
                double sTotal = v.getWidth() * v.getHeight();
                return (int) (100 * sVisible / sTotal);
            } else {
                return -1;
            }

        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem today. While Googling and reading Android reference I found this post and a method I ended up using instead;

```
public final boolean getLocalVisibleRect (Rect r)
```

Nice of them not to only providing Rect but also boolean indicating if View visible at all. On negative side this method is undocumented  :(

Comment: This only tells you if the item is set to visibility(true).  It doesn't tell you if the "visible" item is actually visible within the viewport.

Comment: The code for getLocalVisibleRect doesn't support your claim:
`
    public final boolean getLocalVisibleRect(Rect r) {
        final Point offset = mAttachInfo != null ? mAttachInfo.mPoint : new Point();
        if (getGlobalVisibleRect(r, offset)) {
            r.offset(-offset.x, -offset.y); // make r local
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }`

Answer (score 6):

#### I you want to detect if your `View` is fully `visible`, try with this method:

```
private boolean isViewVisible(View view) {
    Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    mScrollView.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds);
    float top = view.getY();
    float bottom = top + view.getHeight();
    if (scrollBounds.top < top && scrollBounds.bottom > bottom) {
        return true; //View is visible.
    } else {
        return false; //View is NOT visible.
    }
}
```

#### Strictly speaking you can get the visibility of a view with:

```
if (myView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    //VISIBLE
} else {
    //INVISIBLE
}
```

The posible constant values of the visibility in a View are:

**[VISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE)**
This view is visible. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility.

[**INVISIBLE**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)
This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility.

[**GONE**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)
This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility.

Comment: *slow clap.* What the OP wanted to know is, assuming the visibility of the view is View#VISIBLE, how to know if the view itself is visible within a scrollview.

Comment: I just checked on a simple project. The layout has ScrollView and TextView as a child; always returns false even though the TextView is fully visible.

Comment: It returns always false.

Answer (score 6):

Kotlin way;

An extension for listing scroll view's scroll and get an action if child view visible on screen.

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
fun View.setChildViewOnScreenListener(view: View, action: () -> Unit) {
    val visibleScreen = Rect()

    this.setOnTouchListener { _, motionEvent ->
        if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            this.getDrawingRect(visibleScreen)

            if (view.getLocalVisibleRect(visibleScreen)) {
                action()
            }
        }

        false
    }
}
```

Use this extension function for any scrollable view

```
nestedScrollView.setChildViewOnScreenListener(childView) {
               action()
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `FocusAwareScrollView` which notifies when view becomes visible :

```
FocusAwareScrollView focusAwareScrollView = (FocusAwareScrollView) findViewById(R.id.focusAwareScrollView);
    if (focusAwareScrollView != null) {

        ArrayList<View> viewList = new ArrayList<>();
        viewList.add(yourView1);
        viewList.add(yourView2);

        focusAwareScrollView.registerViewSeenCallBack(viewList, new FocusAwareScrollView.OnViewSeenListener() {

            @Override
            public void onViewSeen(View v, int percentageScrolled) {

                if (v == yourView1) {

                    // user have seen view1

                } else if (v == yourView2) {

                    // user have seen view2
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Here is class :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FocusAwareScrollView extends NestedScrollView {

    private List<OnScrollViewListener> onScrollViewListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public FocusAwareScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FocusAwareScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FocusAwareScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public interface OnScrollViewListener {
        void onScrollChanged(FocusAwareScrollView v, int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
    }

    public interface OnViewSeenListener {
        void onViewSeen(View v, int percentageScrolled);
    }

    public void addOnScrollListener(OnScrollViewListener l) {
        onScrollViewListeners.add(l);
    }

    public void removeOnScrollListener(OnScrollViewListener l) {
        onScrollViewListeners.remove(l);
    }

    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        for (int i = onScrollViewListeners.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            onScrollViewListeners.get(i).onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
        }
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }

    @Override
    public void requestChildFocus(View child, View focused) {
        super.requestChildFocus(child, focused);
    }

    private boolean handleViewSeenEvent(View view, int scrollBoundsBottom, int scrollYOffset,
                                        float minSeenPercentage, OnViewSeenListener onViewSeenListener) {
        int loc[] = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
        int viewBottomPos = loc[1] - scrollYOffset + (int) (minSeenPercentage / 100 * view.getMeasuredHeight());
        if (viewBottomPos <= scrollBoundsBottom) {
            int scrollViewHeight = this.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
            int viewPosition = this.getScrollY() + view.getScrollY() + view.getHeight();
            int percentageSeen = (int) ((double) viewPosition / scrollViewHeight * 100);
            onViewSeenListener.onViewSeen(view, percentageSeen);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void registerViewSeenCallBack(final ArrayList<View> views, final OnViewSeenListener onViewSeenListener) {

        final boolean[] viewSeen = new boolean[views.size()];

        FocusAwareScrollView.this.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                final Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
                FocusAwareScrollView.this.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
                final int loc[] = new int[2];
                FocusAwareScrollView.this.getLocationOnScreen(loc);

                FocusAwareScrollView.this.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {

                    boolean allViewsSeen = true;

                    @Override
                    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {

                        for (int index = 0; index < views.size(); index++) {

                            //Change this to adjust criteria
                            float viewSeenPercent = 1;

                            if (!viewSeen[index])
                                viewSeen[index] = handleViewSeenEvent(views.get(index), scrollBounds.bottom, loc[1], viewSeenPercent, onViewSeenListener);

                            if (!viewSeen[index])
                                allViewsSeen = false;
                        }

                        //Remove this if you want continuous callbacks
                        if (allViewsSeen)
                            FocusAwareScrollView.this.setOnScrollChangeListener((NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener) null);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up implementing a combination of two of the Java answers ( @bill-mote https://stackoverflow.com/a/12428154/3686125 and @denys-vasylenko https://stackoverflow.com/a/25528434/3686125 ) in my project as a set of Kotlin extensions, which support either standard vertial ScrollView or HorizontalScrollView controls.

I just tossed these in a Kotlin file named Extensions.kt, no class, just methods.

I used these to determine which item to snap to when a user stops scrolling in various scrollviews in my project:

```
fun View.isPartiallyOrFullyVisible(horizontalScrollView: HorizontalScrollView) : Boolean {
    val scrollBounds = Rect()
    horizontalScrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds)
    return getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)
}

fun View.isPartiallyOrFullyVisible(scrollView: ScrollView) : Boolean {
    val scrollBounds = Rect()
    scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds)
    return getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)
}

fun View.isFullyVisible(horizontalScrollView: HorizontalScrollView) : Boolean {
    val scrollBounds = Rect()
    horizontalScrollView.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds)
    val left = x
    val right = left + width
    return scrollBounds.left < left && scrollBounds.right > right
}

fun View.isFullyVisible(scrollView: ScrollView) : Boolean {
    val scrollBounds = Rect()
    scrollView.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds)
    val top = y
    val bottom = top + height
    return scrollBounds.top < top && scrollBounds.bottom > bottom
}

fun View.isPartiallyVisible(horizontalScrollView: HorizontalScrollView) : Boolean = isPartiallyOrFullyVisible(horizontalScrollView) && !isFullyVisible(horizontalScrollView)
fun View.isPartiallyVisible(scrollView: ScrollView) : Boolean = isPartiallyOrFullyVisible(scrollView) && !isFullyVisible(scrollView)
```

Example usage, iterating through scrollview's LinearLayout children and logging outputs:

```
val linearLayoutChild: LinearLayout = getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
val scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll_view) //Replace with your scrollview control or synthetic accessor
for (i in 0 until linearLayoutChild.childCount) {
    with (linearLayoutChild.getChildAt(i)) {
        Log.d("ScrollView", "child$i left=$left width=$width isPartiallyOrFullyVisible=${isPartiallyOrFullyVisible(scrollView)} isFullyVisible=${isFullyVisible(scrollView)} isPartiallyVisible=${isPartiallyVisible(scrollView)}")
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are using `var` and suppressing ide hint ?

Comment: Oops, I let the IDE correct those incorrectly after the conversion and didn't review that.  Thanks!  Edited.

Answer (score 2):

My way:

```
scrollView.viewTreeObserver?.addOnScrollChangedListener {
     scrollView.getDrawingRect(Rect())
     myViewInsideScrollView.getLocalVisibleRect(Rect()) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its very late. But i have a good solution. Below is the code snippet for getting view visibility percentage in scroll view.

First of all set touch listener on scroll view for getting callback for scroll stop.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch ( event.getAction( ) ) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(mScrollView == null){
                        mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.mScrollView);
                    }
                    int childCount = scrollViewRootChild.getChildCount();

                    //Scroll view location on screen
                    int[] scrollViewLocation = {0,0};
                    mScrollView.getLocationOnScreen(scrollViewLocation);

                    //Scroll view height
                    int scrollViewHeight = mScrollView.getHeight();
                    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++){
                        View child = scrollViewRootChild.getChildAt(i);
                        if(child != null && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                            int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
                            child.getLocationOnScreen(viewLocation);
                            int viewHeight = child.getHeight();
                            getViewVisibilityOnScrollStopped(scrollViewLocation, scrollViewHeight,
                                    viewLocation, viewHeight, (String) child.getTag(), (childCount - (i+1)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 150);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In above code snippet, we are getting call backs for scroll view touch events and post a runnable after 150 millis(Not mandatory) after getting the callback for scroll stopped. In that runnable we will get location of scroll view on the screen and scroll view height. Then get the direct child viewgroup instance of scroll view and get the child counts. In my case direct child of scroll view is LinearLayout named **scrollViewRootChild**. Then iterate all the child views of **scrollViewRootChild**. In above code snippet you can see I am getting the location of the child on the screen in a integer array named **viewLocation**, get height of view in variable name **viewHeight**. Then i called a private method **getViewVisibilityOnScrollStopped**. You can get the understanding of the internal working of this method by reading documentation.

```
/**
 * getViewVisibilityOnScrollStopped
 * @param scrollViewLocation location of scroll view on screen
 * @param scrollViewHeight height of scroll view
 * @param viewLocation location of view on screen, you can use the method of view claas's getLocationOnScreen method.
 * @param viewHeight height of view
 * @param tag tag on view
 * @param childPending number of views pending for iteration.
 */
void getViewVisibilityOnScrollStopped(int[] scrollViewLocation, int scrollViewHeight, int[] viewLocation, int viewHeight, String tag, int childPending) {
    float visiblePercent = 0f;
    int viewBottom = viewHeight + viewLocation[1]; //Get the bottom of view.
    if(viewLocation[1] >= scrollViewLocation[1]) {  //if view's top is inside the scroll view.
        visiblePercent = 100;
        int scrollBottom = scrollViewHeight + scrollViewLocation[1];    //Get the bottom of scroll view 
        if (viewBottom >= scrollBottom) {   //If view's bottom is outside from scroll view
            int visiblePart = scrollBottom - viewLocation[1];  //Find the visible part of view by subtracting view's top from scrollview's bottom  
            visiblePercent = (float) visiblePart / viewHeight * 100;
        }
    }else{      //if view's top is outside the scroll view.
        if(viewBottom > scrollViewLocation[1]){ //if view's bottom is outside the scroll view
            int visiblePart = viewBottom - scrollViewLocation[1]; //Find the visible part of view by subtracting scroll view's top from view's bottom
            visiblePercent = (float) visiblePart / viewHeight * 100;
        }
    }
    if(visiblePercent > 0f){
        visibleWidgets.add(tag);        //List of visible view.
    }
    if(childPending == 0){
        //Do after iterating all children.
    }
}
```

If you feel any improvement in this code please contribute.

Answer (score -1):

Using @Qberticus answer which was to the point but great btw, I compined a bunch of codes to check if whenever a scrollview is called and got scrolled it trigger the @Qberticus answer and you can do whatever you want, in my case I have a social network containing videos so when the view is drawed on the screen I play the video same idea like facebook and Instagram.
Here's the code:

```
mainscrollview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onScrollChanged() {
                        //mainscrollview is my scrollview that have inside it a linearlayout containing many child views.
                        Rect bounds = new Rect();
                         for(int xx=1;xx<=postslayoutindex;xx++)
                         {

                          //postslayoutindex is the index of how many posts are read.
                          //postslayoutchild is the main layout for the posts.
                        if(postslayoutchild[xx]!=null){

                            postslayoutchild[xx].getHitRect(bounds);

                        Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
                        mainscrollview.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds);

                        if(Rect.intersects(scrollBounds, bounds))
                        {
                            vidPreview[xx].startPlaywithoutstoppping();
                         //I made my own custom video player using textureview and initialized it globally in the class as an array so I can access it from anywhere.
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }


                        }
                    }
                    }
                });
```