# Get visible area in ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I have linear layout in a ScrollView, I have added a set of ImageButton which can now scroll. How do I get the set of visible ImageButton on the screen.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="250dp"        
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This should help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628800/android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible

Comment: This link was useful I got it - Thanks