# Android - HorizontalScrollView - get view in focus (or index of it)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-scroll

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` containing a `LinearLayout`, which in turn contains a couple of `FrameLayout`s. Each `FrameLayout` contains the layout of a `Fragment`. Now I'm trying to get the view, i.e. `FrameLayout`, which is currently visible or in focus within the `HorizontalScrollView`. As soon as I have the view in focus I could get it's index within the `LinearLayout`.

I've tried the following, but nothing works:

- HorizontalScrollView.findFocus() - returns null
- LinearLayout.findFocus() - returns null
- LinearLayout.getFocusedChild() - returns null
- FrameLayout.hasFocus() - returns false for all `FrameLayout`s

I could also try to figure out which child of the `LinearLayout` has focus, by doing calculations based on current X-position of each child. However, calling `getX()` on each child always returns "0.0".

Does anyone have an idea how to get the view in focus (or even better it's index within the `LinearLayout`)?

Comment: Would you mind sharing with us why you'd want to do such thing? I'm just curious.

Comment: I need to keep track which of the fragments is visible for logging purposes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the answer to this question: [android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628800/android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible) I came up with the following solution:

```
Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
MyHorizontalScrollView.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds);
Rect childBounds = new Rect();      
for (int i = 0; i < MyLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    MyLinearLayout.getChildAt(i).getHitRect(childBounds);
    if(scrollBounds.contains(childBounds)) {
        IndexOfVisibleChild = i;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can get count of child views that are currently visible for scrollbar view?

Comment: any solution/suggestion here?

Comment: haven't done anything with Android in ages, but if you incrementing a counter in the above if-statement should do the trick