# How to know which list item is visible to user?

Tags: android, listview

I recorded videos through my app,And i stored in memory card.

After i get those videos and added to list view .

Based on screen size only one video is visible to user.

If user scroll up and down and stop.

At that point i want to know which one is in front of user.

If any one know the solution please help me.or any other way to do

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740089/android-getting-a-count-of-the-visible-children-in-a-listview

Comment: Also check the provided link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874260/determine-if-a-view-is-on-screen-android

Answer (score 11):

OK, there are two methods could help you.

```
ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()
ListView.getLastVisiblePosition()
```

Look [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) for details.

Comment: `ListView` extends `AdapterView`. Hence, JavaDoc for `ListView` will not help a lot, use [JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition()) für `AdapterView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Adapter to populate your list,
the last visible item will be the one that pops into your latest [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29).

Meaning, if you'll keep track of what was the latest `Position` - you'll store the position of the last visible item.

Comment: First part of answer is not right ultimately. Android can pre-cache, and if scrolling up and down you need to find out how many items user can see.

Comment: @MarekSebera you are right, but the guy said `Based on screen size only one video is visible to user.`

Answer (score 0):

Given Marek Sebera's comment - it is indeed true that `getView` won't be 100% reliable, you can just use [`getFirstVisiblePosition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29) in the adapter.

(That should be enough if only one video is visible at a time.)

Answer (score 0):

As you are showing only one item of list so you can create a function in your Adapter class that will gives you id of currently visible child. like

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    int slectedChild;  // selectedChild will save currently visible child's id

> public int getSelectedChild(){ // this function will return id of currently visible child 
>        return selectedChild;  
>   }
>
> // public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container)  
>   {
>
> selectedChild=position;  // update value selectedChild in side getView() function.
>  
>   ....
>   }
>   }

Comment: sorry,i didn't get u.if u don't mind please give some sample.thanks for u'r replay.