# How to determine a component active in view port of device?

Tags: listview, react-native, scrollview, screen, native-base

I have **React Native** long **list view** (list of cards).
How can I detect the current card is active in list view (visible on screen)?

To be exact, like **Instagram** that when you *pause scrolling* it *start playing* video **automatically**.

based on [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743124/how-to-know-which-list-item-is-visible-to-user?rq=1) in Android we can use :

```
ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()
ListView.getLastVisiblePosition()
```

But in React native I couldn't find a solution.
Here is my code:

```
<List>
    <ListItem>
      <Card>
        <CardItem>
            <Left style={{marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10}}>
                <Thumbnail
                    circular
                    source={{uri: speaker.image}}/>
                <Text>
                    {speaker.first_name} {speaker.last_name}
                </Text>
                <Left>
                    <Text note style={{paddingLeft: 5}}>
                        {speaker.company}
                    </Text>
                </Left>
            </Left>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
   </listItem>
 </list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Flatlist` instead of `listview` here, it provides `onViewableItemsChanged` to get current visible item, see below code:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            arrData: [],
        }
        this.handleViewableItemsChanged = this.handleViewableItemsChanged.bind(this)
        this.viewabilityConfig = {viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50}
    }

    handleViewableItemsChanged(info) {
        console.log(info)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.arrData}
                    horizontal={true}
                    pagingEnabled={true}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    onViewableItemsChanged={this.handleViewableItemsChanged}
                    viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}

                    renderItem={({item}) =>
                        // Your display Items
                    }
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

You can refer the URL for more details: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

Comment: thanks, but it not updating while scrolling or after scrolling stops!

Comment: I solved the problem based on your advice and thanks a lot for that. here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737287/react-native-onviewableitemschanged-not-working-while-scrolling-on-dynamic-dat