# React Native "onViewableItemsChanged" not working while scrolling on dynamic data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base, react-native-flatlist

I have a React Native FlatList.
base on [Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#onviewableitemschanged) I used **onViewableItemsChanged** for getting the current showing item on the screen. but while scrolling or when scrolling stops nothing happens and I can't get the current Id.
How Can I use it in correct way?

```
export default class TimeLine extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderTimeline = this.renderTimeline.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        timeline: [],
    };
    this.handleViewableItemsChanged = this.handleViewableItemsChanged.bind(this);
    this.viewabilityConfig = {
        itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50,
    };
}
...
renderTimelineList(timeline_data) {


    return (

        <Card key={timeline_data.unique_id}>
            <CardItem style={styles.header}>
                <Left>
                    <Icon type="MaterialIcons" name={this.timelineIcon(timeline_data.type)}/>
                    <Body>
                    <Text style={styles.header_title}>{timeline_data.title}</Text>

                    </Body>
                </Left>
            </CardItem>

            <CardItem>
                {this.renderTimeline(timeline_data)}
            </CardItem>

            <CardItem>
                <Left>
                    <Icon small name="time" style={styles.small_font}/>
                    <Text note style={styles.small_font}>{timeline_data.release_date}</Text>
                </Left>
                <Right>
                    <Text note style={styles.small_font}>{timeline_data.duration}</Text>
                </Right>
            </CardItem>
        </Card>
    );


}
render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Content>
                <FlatList
                    key={this.state.key}
                    onViewableItemsChanged={this.handleViewableItemsChanged}
                    viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}
                    data={this.state.timeline}
                    renderItem={({item}) => this.renderTimelineList(item)}
                />
            </Content>
        </Container>
    );
};
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get currently visible index in RN flat list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868284/how-to-get-currently-visible-index-in-rn-flat-list)

Comment: my question is different from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.
The problem was because of I was trying to populate the data with **Ajax**.
To solve that I ran the request from the **Parent** component and passed it in `props`
and inside the **constructor of the class** if filled the state for my array.

Another thing that you should consider is that you should render the whole `FlatList` inside a `View`.

here is my final code:

```
export default class TimeLine extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.viewabilityConfig = {
        minimumViewTime: 500,
        viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 60,
    };
}
render() {
    const {timeline} = this.state;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={timeline}
                renderItem={({item}) => this.renderTimelineList(item)}
                viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}
                onViewableItemsChanged={({viewableItems}) => this.handleViewableItemsChanged(viewableItems)}
            />
        </View>
    );

};
}
```

Comment: this error seems to be related by using other parent components (Container, Content)...

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that you implement [keyExtractor](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#keyextractor) correctly (or implement it if you haven't already).

In my case `keyExtractor` was returning null for many children, and `onViewableItemsChanged` would not dispatch for those.

Comment: this is right, if there is some issue with keyExtractor it does not work..