# How to know whether View inside Scroll is Visible completely or no

Tags: android, scrollview, android-imageview, android-scrollview

There is scroll view between header(at the top of screen) and Tabs(Bottom of the screen). I want to know that whether the ImageView which is inside the ScrollView is fully visible or not on phone screen window.

[image]

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25528434/3148266

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to do the following way (the approach is similar to one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542912/determining-the-entry-shown-is-listview/17544173#17544173)).

E.g. You have the following xml (I'm not sure what are header and tabs so they are missed):

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroller">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:src="@drawable/image001"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</ScrollView>
```

Then activity might look like the following:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    private ScrollView mScroll = null;
    private ImageView mImage = null;

    private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener mLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            final Rect imageRect = new Rect(0, 0, mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight());
            final Rect imageVisibleRect = new Rect(imageRect);

            mScroll.getChildVisibleRect(mImage, imageVisibleRect, null);

            if (imageVisibleRect.height() < imageRect.height() ||
                    imageVisibleRect.width() < imageRect.width()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "image is not fully visible");
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "image is fully visible");
            }

            mScroll.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(mLayoutListener);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Show the layout with the test view
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
        mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        mScroll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(mLayoutListener);
    }
}
```

In case of small image it will log: image is fully visible.

However, You should be aware about the following inconsistency (as per my understanding): if You have big image, but doing scaling to it (e.g. you set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`) when it will look scaled, but actual `ImageView` height will be as full height of the image (and `ScrollView` will be even scrolling), so [adjustViewBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) might be needed. The reason for that behavious is that `FrameLayout` [doesn't care about layout_width and layout_height of childs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#FrameLayout_Layout).