# Determining the entry shown is listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll

i am trying to send data in a listview when a button is clicked.

However my listview show 2 row on at once one full row and one partial row . Is there a way i can determine which row is showing partial and which is showing fully.

I am able to get the index that is showing only. is there another approach ?

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
        Rect r = new Rect ();
        View child = recordListview.getChildAt(view.getFirstVisiblePosition());    // first visible child
        if (child == null)
            return; 
        double height = child.getHeight () * 1.0;

        recordListview.getChildVisibleRect (child, r, null);
        Log.d("Visible1 ", view.getFirstVisiblePosition() + "  "  + height + "  " + r.height()  );

        if (Math.abs (r.height ()) < height / 2.0) {
                    // show next child
            recordListview.smoothScrollToPosition(view.getFirstVisiblePosition()+1);
            Log.d("Visible1 Location", view.getFirstVisiblePosition() +1+ "");
        }

        else {
            recordListview.smoothScrollToPosition(view.getFirstVisiblePosition());
            Log.d("Visible1 Location", view.getFirstVisiblePosition()+ "");
        }

    }
}
});
```

Comment: Have You tried getChildVisibleRect() ?

Comment: @sandrstar i have updated my code with the example shown at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338509/android-listview-stop-scrolling-at-whole-row-position . This causes my listview to be no longer scrollable.

Comment: Is onScroll() called? I think You need to use onScrollStateChanged(), detect SCROLL_STATE_IDLE and then do your logic.

Comment: @sandrstar Yes onscrolled is fired . however , r.height is always zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems You've understood documentation of [getChildVisibleRect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#getChildVisibleRect%28android.view.View,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Point%29) incorrectly.

It mentions:

> r     The input rectangle, defined in the child coordinate system. Will
>   be overwritten to contain the resulting visible rectangle, expressed
>   in global (root) coordinates

So, if You're providing empty rectangle **in the child coordinate** then it can be translated only into empty visible rectagle, right?

For me this code seems to work:

```
recordListview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(final AbsListView view, final int scrollState) {
        if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            final View child = recordListview.getChildAt(view.getFirstVisiblePosition());

            if (child == null) {
                return;
            }

            final Rect r = new Rect (0, 0, child.getWidth(), child.getHeight());
            final double height = child.getHeight () * 1.0;

            recordListview.getChildVisibleRect(child, r, null);
            Log.d("Visible1 ", view.getFirstVisiblePosition() + "  "  + height + "  " + r.height());

            if (Math.abs (r.height ()) < height / 2.0) {
                // show next child
                recordListview.smoothScrollToPosition(view.getFirstVisiblePosition()+1);
                Log.d("Visible1 Location", view.getFirstVisiblePosition() +1+ "");
            } else {
                recordListview.smoothScrollToPosition(view.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                Log.d("Visible1 Location", view.getFirstVisiblePosition()+ "");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, final int firstVisibleItem, final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {
        // nothing to do here
    }
});
```

Regarding initial question about determining which view is visible fully and which is not, I would suggest to use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(final AbsListView view, final int scrollState) {
    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

        final int firstVisiblePosition = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View child = recordListview.getChildAt(firstVisiblePosition);

        if (child == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mListItemsOnScreen == 0) {
            // number of total visible items, including items which are not fully visible
            mListItemsOnScreen = (int) Math.ceil(((double)recordListview.getHeight()) / (child.getHeight() + recordListview.getDividerHeight()));
        }

        final Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, child.getWidth(), child.getHeight());
        final double height = child.getHeight();

        recordListview.getChildVisibleRect(child, r, null);
        Log.d("Visible1", " items till " + firstVisiblePosition + " are not visible");
        // Check top item
        Log.d("Visible1", firstVisiblePosition + " is visible " + (r.height() >= height ? " fully" : "partially"));
        // check bottom item
        child = recordListview.getChildAt(firstVisiblePosition + mListItemsOnScreen);

        if (child != null) {
            r.set(0, 0, child.getWidth(), child.getHeight());
            recordListview.getChildVisibleRect(child, r, null);

            Log.d("Visible1", " items from " + firstVisiblePosition + " till " + (firstVisiblePosition + mListItemsOnScreen) + " are fully visible");
            Log.d("Visible1", (firstVisiblePosition + mListItemsOnScreen) + " is visible " + (r.height() >= height ? " fully" : "partially"));
        } else {
            Log.d("Visible1", " items from " + firstVisiblePosition + " till " + (firstVisiblePosition + mListItemsOnScreen) + " are fully visible");
            Log.d("Visible1", (firstVisiblePosition + mListItemsOnScreen) + " is invisible ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sandstar , i tried the solution above . The scroll from item 0 to 1 works fine nut when i scroll from item 1 to 2 . The list start to move  from 1 - 2 - 1 - 2 ... indefinetly.

`07-10 02:49:46.930: D/Visible1(2772): 1  190.0  190 2
07-10 02:49:46.930: D/Visible1 Location(2772): 1
07-10 02:49:46.980: D/Visible1(2772): 1  190.0  52 2
07-10 02:49:46.980: D/Visible1 Location(2772): 2
07-10 02:49:47.040: D/Visible1(2772): 1  190.0  190 2
07-10 02:49:47.070: D/Visible1 Location(2772): 1
07-10 02:49:47.113: D/Visible1(2772): 1  190.0  52 2
`

Comment: What are You trying to achieve? Actually, You question is 'way determine which row is showing partial' - was You able to achieve it?

Comment: Yes thats right . I am trying to determine which row is shown and then scroll to the row which have the biggest area shown. I am just curious why will it work for the scroll of item 0 to 1 and not for subsequent scroll.

Comment: I've provided the code to determine which view is visible and which is not (or visible partially). I think 2 items is a corner case and, probably, usage of Math.abs (r.height ()) < height / 2 is not valid for it. However, I think it shouldn't be a problem for You to determine exact logic of checks for 2 two items (logging of exact values of visible heights would help). I've tested with 10 items list, because it's a common case for your question.

Comment: Hi sandrstar , thanks for the code. I am trying them now. Can you share what is assigned to the variable mListItemsOnScreen ?

Comment: It's just number of visible item of the list, declared as private int mListItemsOnScreen = 0;