# android: how to draw a displayed part of scrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, ondraw

How should we draw only the displayed part of a custom scroll view? Someone has an exemple of that?

Comment: May This help you: Follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628800/android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible

Comment: I found getScrollX() and getScrollY() to resolve my problem. However the getDrawingRect() in this link is more elegant and provide the width and height of the displayed part. Thanks