# Get the visible area of a view

Tags: java, android

I've got an `Activity` with a transparent (bottom->up) `SlidingDrawer` on it. I'd like to get the width and height of its visible area only, as I scroll it up the screen. Is it possible? I figured I'd make it with any of the `getLocalVisibleRect()` and `getGlobalVisibleRect()` methods, but I was wrong, as they return the layout rectangle.

Comment: I think this will surely help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628800/android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it! It's possible to measure the visible area of the `SlidingDrawer` getting the (X, Y) coordinates of its handle on the screen.

```
mySlidingDrawer.getHandle().getY();
mySlidingDrawer.getHandle().getX();
```