# how to know child views indices which are currently displaying on screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, scrollview

I have multiple views inside horizontalScrollView and is currently showing 3 views at a time on screen. When user scroll through Horizontalscrollview, some different views which are previously being hidden are now displayed on screen.

So how do I know the indices of child views which are currently displaying on screen. Please suggest some way of doing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628800/android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible. The best answer seems to be this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12428154/974731

Comment: Thanks mate. I was searching this for couple of hours