# Cannot find if a view is not visible on screen in a ScrollView. Always returns true

Tags: android, scrollview

I have been trying to determine if a TextView can be seen on the screen, if not I want to display a small text saying "Scroll To Read". I have tried various methods from questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628800/android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible) and many others too. In the detail fragment of my Master-Detail Layout, I have a fragment, which contains a FrameLayout. This framelayout has a ScrollView in the back and a textview in the front saying "Scroll To Read" (which I would keep invisible until the textview with news article in the scrollview is not visible). For eg, I wont display the "Scroll To Read" textview [here](http://puu.sh/8Pwsk.png) or [here](http://puu.sh/8PwyX.png), but would display [here](http://puu.sh/8PwtC.png). Right now, it is visible just for testing purposes.

The layout is [here](http://pastebin.com/HHgrA7tr). The scrollview is `scroller`. When image is available viewstub 
`article_header_stub_import` is used which is given in the bottom of the file. I want to check if TextView `body` is visible or not. I added `wastedText` below the body just for checking but it was also shown visible in all cases.

I have tried different things with the solutions, like getting getHitRect with `scrollingLinearLayout` or `scroller` or `detailFrameLayout` and even with the detail fragment. The code is similar to the question I linked and I am just using Log.d(...) to see check with the if-else case.

I am using Picasso to load the image and doing the coding in the success callback of picasso, for eg this:

```
picassoInstance.load(mImageURL).into(mMainImageView, new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d(TAG_ASYNC, "Image Loaded");
                mTestTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
                mScrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
                if (mTestTextView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
                    // Any portion of the imageView, even a single pixel, is
                    // within the visible window
                    Log.d(TAG_ASYNC, "is visible");
                } else {
                    // NONE of the imageView is within the visible window
                    Log.d(TAG_ASYNC, "not visible");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

I have also tried getHeight, getTop, getBottom etc. but all returns 0.

Comment: Cannot you use: `scrollView.getChildVisibleRect(child, r, offset)`?

Comment: Or compare `scrollView.getScrollY()` with `textView.getY()`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I added this at the place of `mScrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);` but it always returning false. Does it need that `child` should be fully visible or even a pixel of it would suffice. I am also trying to use `.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener` to compare heights.

Comment: for the second comment all the child views are returning getHeight, getY etc as 0. I am doing this in onPostExecute of asynctask so all the views are already laid out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to use the Rect. So I searched for "view getheight is always 0". Although I still dont understand why the height was returning 0 (although this is happening in onPostExecute of AsyncTask AND after the image is loaded by Picasso), I used the GlobalListener to get the height and compare with the screen.

```
picassoInstance.load(mImageURL).into(mMainImageView, new Callback() {

@Override
public void onSuccess() {
    Log.d(TAG_ASYNC, "Image Loaded");

    mMainImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    //Get Display metrics according to the SDK
                    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                    Point screen = new Point();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                        display.getSize(screen);
                    } else {
                        screen.x = display.getWidth();
                        screen.y = display.getHeight();
                    }

                    //StatusBar Height
                    int statusBarHeight = 0;
                    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
                    if (resId > 0) {
                        statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resId);
                    }

                    //ActionBar Height
                    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
                    int actionBarHeight = 0;
                    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
                        actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,
                                getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    }

                    //Check
                    Log.d(TAG_ASYNC, "mSubtitleLayout " + mSubtitleLayout.getHeight());
                    Log.d(TAG_ASYNC, "mMainImageView " + mMainImageView.getHeight());
                    Log.d(TAG_ASYNC, "mArticleTextView " + mArticleTextView.getTop());
                    Log.d(TAG_ASYNC, "total height " + screen.y);
                    Log.d(TAG_ASYNC, "status bar " + statusBarHeight);
                    Log.d(TAG_ASYNC, "action bar " + actionBarHeight);

                    //Boolean to check if image+subtitle is large enough.
                    //If yes, then display "Scroll To Read"
                    displayScrollToRead = (screen.y - statusBarHeight - actionBarHeight) < (mArticleTextView
                            .getTop()) * 1.08;
                    Log.d(TAG_ASYNC, "displayScrollToRead " + displayScrollToRead);

                    if (displayScrollToRead) {
                        mScrollToReadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Log.d(TAG_ASYNC, "Visiblity - " + mScrollToReadLayout.getVisibility());
                    }

                    //remove GlobalLayoutListener according to SDK
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
                        mMainImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        mMainImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }

                }

            });

}

@Override
public void onError() {

    Log.d(TAG_ASYNC, "IMAGE WAS NOT LOADED!!!");

}
});
```