# If ImageView is in Region, do something

Tags: android, imageview, draggable, region

At the moment I have Regions set up in my activity for touches, like this:

```
onTouch(...){
    int x = (int) ev.getX();
    int y = (int) ev.getY();

   if (x >= 370 && x <= 500 && y >= 250 && y <= 420) {
            //do something....
       }
```

The above code is in an `onTouch` method to detect if a touch passes through the Region.

Now I'm trying to get an image to follow the finger around the screen while still being able to interact with the Regions. 
I have an `ImageView` that I can drag around the screen, using the `onDrag` method, however when I drag it through the Region nothing happens.

I think something like this might work but I'm not sure how to actually code it:

```
    if ImageView (being dragged by finger) is in the area of 
         (x >= 370 && x <= 500 && y >= 250 && y <= 420) {
            //do something...
        }
```

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4629167/2389078) is everything you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually figured it out:

```
 ImageView j = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
 final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
 final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

   if (X >= 370 && X <= 500 && Y >= 250 && Y <= 420) {
            j.//do whatever...
      }
```