# How to know a view is showing in physical screen or not?

Tags: android, view, visibility

I want to know when a view of my layout is showing in physical screen. You know in some apps that uses `ScrollView`, you must scroll down to see other views. I want to know when a view like `Button` or `TextView` or another view is showing in physical screen to do some job. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: how to check if a View inside of ScrollView is visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628800/android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
if (view.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
    // Any portion of the view, even a single pixel, is within the visible window
} else {
    // NONE of the view is within the visible window
}
```

Comment: thanks. it worked. i have another question, can i ask it here? it is sequence of this question.

Comment: @karimkhan, Yes, you may. If my answer is correct, accept it please

Comment: yes sure. I have six gridview in my layout. And i want to load images in them when user see them in physical screen. How can i do that with your answer?

Comment: @karimkhan, then you don't need my Answer. Just use a Picasso or UniversalImageLoader. In your adapter method, when you inflating items, find your imageview and do this(for picasso):`Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);` Here is link to picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @karimkhan, please, let me know if you need any help

Comment: this is my adapter initializing method.http://s3.picofile.com/file/8199083734/123.PNG, and i load images from asset folder.

Comment: @karimkhan, show me code of `GridviewAdapter` please

Comment: sorry [this is in gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c0c0b0580356263dcf4)

Comment: @karimkhan, I try this: https://gist.github.com/AlexanderGarmash/eb16e87c38bedfce252c

Comment: @karimkhan, don't forget add Picasso library to your project

Comment: @karimkhan, I have updated my gist file. I added `file:///android_asset/`

Comment: then what i do for loading them when they are in physical screen?

Comment: @karimkhan, you don't need load bitmaps manually. This is very bad practice. You don't need care about showing bitmaps when they physical at screen. This will do Picasso. Just use this library and no problem will occured

Comment: [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4a65ba6de75709b65cd6) is my adapter initializing method. how can i change it to your way?

Comment: @karimkhan, checkout this: https://gist.github.com/AlexanderGarmash/eb16e87c38bedfce252c

Comment: @karimkhan, I updated gist. Instead of `List<String> listWithImageNames` I added `Integer[] listWithImageNames`, and in `getView` use `listWithImageNames` instead `flagArray`

Comment: Of course it will solve problem with OOM. Because your variant is absolutely wrong

Comment: one question for me is that what i can use here   Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imag‌​eView) instead of context inside gridviewadapter class.

Comment: @karimkhan, you should use `activity`. You defined it like: `private Activity activity;`. Use it instead context

Comment: when i load images, there is a white background appear before image load in items of gridview. how can i insert a loading inside it before image load.

Comment: I must place Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView); inside gridviewadapter?

Comment: @karimkhan, yes instead `Picasso.with(context).load(listWithImageNames[position]).into(view.imgViewFlag);`

Comment: i placed a gif load inside placehodler method but it is not loading. just show loading like a jpeg image constant

Comment: I found that i must use progressbar for that.