# How to detect the top and bottom coordinates of the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

I have the following code that works:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
if(b != null) {
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    parentLayout.getHitRect(bounds);
    if(b.getLocalVisibleRect(bounds)) {
        //it is visible, do code
    }
}
```

Question: How can I change the code so that the I do what I am currently doing inside `if(b.getLocalVisibleRect(bounds))` but when the middle of or the complete button has appeared?
With my code now, I can detect when the upper edge of the button has appeared. But it would be best if I was able to detect when almost all of the button has appeared.

Comment: what is the use case for doing this?

Comment: @RahulTiwari: I am doing an animation of another element and I think that if I was more accurate the transition would be perfect. Now it is ok, but since I am learning android I want to see how things can improve

Comment: Please have a look at this link and see the third answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628800/android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible

Comment: This is not correct. This does not show if the button is part of the visible screen

Comment: @jim I misunderstand your question.I have edited my answer please try it now.

Comment: What is the variable `r`?

Comment: replace it with bounds

Comment: Tried it, I don't see any difference with my approach

Comment: check the link i provide you in answer