# Calculate how much time the user looks at recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a screen with a list of products implemented using a recyclerview. 
I am looking for a way to check how much time the user spends looking at a certain item in the list. In this way I can know in which items is he interested so I can build him an "maybe interested in" list. More exactly..if a user stays on that item more than x seconds I retain that item id and do the rest... Any kind of ideea or help helps me alot. Thanks

Comment: Are you opening a new view for each item? If so, you could start a timer on opening and check the value on closing this view. Else, you could play with the "onScrollStateListener" for RecyclerView.

Comment: I use the ViewHolder pattern to display the views. I was thinking to use the OnBindViewHolder to get the position of the adapter (and this way the item) that is currentlly viewed. But for this approach I need to have an item covering the whole screen which can bring responsiveness issues.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to do something similar to [Android: how to check if a View inside of ScrollView is visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628800/android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible/12428154#12428154) to determine which view is actually within the visible screen.  It can be modified slightly to detect if the entire view is visible rather than only a portion.

You're probably also going to have to track the time started/stopped viewing in the recycle view's adapter.

Comment: Is there a way I can use getDrawingRect inside the adapter to get the recyclerview's visible bounds?

Answer (score 1):

I don't like idea to display user something like "maybe interested in" based on your logic. Because user has seen it already. It can be super annoying if I buy computer mouse and then I see it on every Activity I visit... I'd rather see some items from same category as most seen items but not the most seen items themself. That's why I highly suggest you to count time inside item details Activities (`onStart`/`onStop` methods)

But Answer can be something like this:
See following methods:

[`RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder%28VH,%20int%29) (View created because it is most likely going to be visible to user)

[`RecyclerView.Adapter.onViewRecycled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewRecycled%28VH%29) (View will be recycled - 100% not visible on screen)

You can create some `Map` or another database column (don't know your project structure) to store item id's and timestamps from

```
private class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    long itemId;
    long start;

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BindingHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemId = ...;
    holder.start = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(BindingHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long difference = currentTime - holder.start;
    // store result
    map.put(holder.itemId, difference);
    // to better match your needs update map item and do not overwrite it
}
```

This is not 100% solution, but is the simplest one.

To implement it inside Activities use same `System.currentTimeMillis()` method inside `onStart` and `onStop` methods (or `onResume`/`onPause`). See [Acticity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) so that you know where you need it.

Comment: Never implemented nor tested so it may contain some errors :)

Comment: As you can see in the comment i made just 1 min before your answer this was the way I wanted to do it, but currently I have a problem because my item is not covering the whole screen so OnBindViewHolder will get 2 items even if one is barely visible. But onViewRecycled may help me...

Comment: Or pick just first one if they are that large... users tends to look on top of the page not bottom

Comment: And how do I know which one is the first if onBind is called on every item the same way?

Comment: `holder.getAdapterPosition()` returns you position in adapter... smallest available is first...

Comment: hmm on second though... the first visible item might be the item with only 1px visible displayed on top. You have to rethink this

Comment: The thing is that if I call holder.getAdapterPosition() inside onBindViewHolder it will get me the next item that is drawn (next than the one i'm interested if i scroll down and previous if I scroll up). I need the already visible one.