# Check a child view visible on screen or not in NestedScrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

In my activity, I have a long scrollview contains multiple views, when a user is scrolling up or down, I have to check whether a textview is visible or not on screen.

Please help me .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: how to check if a View inside of ScrollView is visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628800/android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use next code:

```
Rect mReact = new Rect();
scrollView.getHitRect(mReact);
if (mView.getLocalVisibleRect(mReact)) {
// visible
} else {
// invisible
}
```

Comment: Neat solution dude.

Comment: this is not working for me